# Image rotation in Unity 2d

Tags: c, unity-game-engine

please tell me how to make it rotate 90 degrees when you click on the picture? At first, the picture is at 0, then the player clicked for the first time, the picture stood up = 90 degrees, then it became 180 again. How can this be implemented in Unity 2d ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, if anyone needs:

```
  public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 50f * Time.deltaTime, 90);
    }
```